# CodeDeploy unsets LoadBalancer while cloning AutoScalingGroup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

After CodeDeploy clones AutoScalingGroup, it leaves LoadBalancer field empty. This leads to following problem: when instance webserver dies, ELB does not understand instance is "down", this instance is not replaced automatically.
However, if i set LoadBalancer manually, it will work fine afterwards.

I watched how new ASG is cloned. There is possibility to suspend some processes while instance is booting. So as i understand, CodeDeploy suspends all actions related to ELB, because it uses his own automatic scripts to un-attach old instances and attach new ones to ELB.

[fresh ASG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09lSw.png)

I dont use any custom attach or un-attach scripts myself.

Otherwise deployment runs ok, and new instances are created correctly.

Comment: What does the deployment configuration looks like? Is it in place or a blue green deployment?

Comment: blue-green deployment...

Comment: Whats the configuration in the deployment group? "Instances in the original environment are deregistered and handled according to your specification in the deployment group, either terminated or kept running." http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/welcome.html#welcome-deployment-overview-blue-green

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with the team and apparently what's going on is that CodeDeploy now manages the load balancer for you. That is very confusing to customers to not see the ELB associated with that AutoScalingGroup. This allows CodeDeploy to control and make sure that the deployment finishes before binding the to the load balancer.

-Asaf